# facing error in build cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

```
C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace>cd hello

C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello>cordova build<br>
The provided path "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello\platforms\android" is not an
 Android project.
```

---

1.My question is why hello is not a android project?
2.when i use cordova build it gives me build.xml does not exit? 
3.steps i fallow is.....
a)Node.js
                        (b)npm install -g cordova
                        (c)set path env.variables
                        (d)set ant env.variables
                        (e)cordova create.....project name
                        (f)cordova platform add android
                        (g)cordova build
after this it showing its not a android project......I hope you will assist me!! ThankYou..

Comment: have you installed Android SDK tools?

Comment: yes!! and set the path also...sdk tools and platform-tools

Comment: can you run all cordova commands with the `-d` flag agian. It will give more detailed error information. i.e `cordova -d create hello`

Comment: C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace>cordova -d create hello com.example.hello "hello"
Creating a new cordova project with name "hello" and id "com.example.hello" at l
ocation "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello"
Using stock cordova hello-world application.
cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Copying stock Cordova www assets into "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello\www"

Comment: delete the hello directory and perform all the step again and as said earlier use the `-d` flag. And if you get an error during `cordova -d build` then paste the error in your question.

Comment: As you said i delete hello directory and then use cordova -d create hello then i got......this.....C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace>cordova -d create hello
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hello
cordova" at location "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello"
Using stock cordova hello-world application.
cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Copying stock Cordova www assets into "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello\www"

Comment: C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
        Android target: undefined

Comment: C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace>cordova -d build
CordovaError: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
    at Object.cdProjectRoot (C:\Users\rtickoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js:106:15)
    at build (C:\Users\rtickoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mod
ules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\build.js:29:36)
    at cli (C:\Users\rtickoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js
:189:26)

Comment: you need to run the `cordova -d build` command in the **hello** directory. i.e  C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello>cordova -d build

Comment: ok first nmp install -d cordova then make hello dir. in hello cordova -d build ....C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello>cordova -d build
CordovaError: The provided path "C:\Users\rtickoo\workspace\hello\platforms\andr
oid" is not an Android project.
    at Object.android_parser (C:\Users\rtickoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\android_parser.js:37:15)
    at C:\Users\rtickoo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co
rdova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:54:23

Comment: this is one last try. There should be a **folder** `.cordova` in `"C:\Users\rtickoo\"` directory. Delete the **.cordova** folder. Then delete the *hello* directory in the `workspace` and run **all** the cordova commands again.

Comment: frank:Finally it works...Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a folder **.cordova** in `"C:\Users\rtickoo\"` directory. Delete the **.cordova** folder. Then delete the **hello** directory in the workspace and run **all** the **cordova** commands again.